# Keydown pressed for left does not update for Keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object on `canvas` that I would like to move with keyboard events,

My event function is as follows

```
function onKeyDown(evt) {
if (evt.keyCode == 40) { downDown = true;}
if (evt.keyCode == 39) { rightDown = true;}
if (evt.keyCode == 38) { upDown = true;}
if (evt.keyCode == 37) { leftDown = true;}
}
```

and my `onKeyUp` function is the same except with `false` as the value

then I attach it as

```
$(document).keydown(onKeyDown);
$(document).keyup(onKeyUp);
```

I have a draw function that is called within my init as `intv = setInterval(draw, 10);` with the following statements

```
                            if (rightDown) { x += dx;}
                            if (upDown) { y -= dy;}
                            if (downDown) { y += dy;}
                            if (leftDown) {x -= dx;}
```

Everything except the -x direction (left Down) works well. Such that I can move the object up,right and down. When left is pressed the object continues moving left. Are my conditional statements setup improperly ?

The full demo is at http://jsfiddle.net/avSvu/

Comment: Could you post a demo? maybe on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Soumya92 http://jsfiddle.net/avSvu/

Comment: Stupid little demo I made using two vars, don't know if it helps... (http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/jL2u2/1/)

Comment: You don't need 4 variables to store the key-press information. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950575/how-to-move-a-div-with-arrow-keys/4951670#4951670 One object stores the information for all 4 arrow keys. It makes the JavaScript code simpler, too.

Comment: @Šime Vidas Thanks that is a very neat thing, though I am still trying to figure out why one of the directions is not working properly.

Comment: @Philippe I think @Ivo found out why your code doesn't work...

Comment: @Šime yeah you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function onKeyUp(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 40) { downDown = false;}
    ...

    //      v----- capital K ?
    if (evt.KeyCode == 37) { leftDown = false;}
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/avSvu/5/

Comment: You nailed it, good job. I looked that over for a good 5 minutes and didn't see it. I blame jsFiddle's font selection. ;p

Comment: @Philippe Check out the link in the answer above. It is your exact code but with the capital K corrected. As you can see, it works once you correct that.

Comment: I see it now oO I am so blind. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can have improvements like you should not have to check the keycode every time and you can reuse the same function to turn flip the boolean flags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title></title>
  </head>  
  <body>

    <div id="out1"></div>
    <div id="out2"></div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">


      (function(){

        var downDown = false;
        var rightDown = false;
        var upDown = false;
        var leftDown = false;

        function onKeyUpDown(evt,isDown) {
          var keyCode = evt.keyCode;
          jQuery("#out1").html(keyCode);
          if (keyCode  == 40) { downDown = isDown;}
          else if (keyCode == 39) { rightDown = isDown;}
          else if (keyCode == 38) { upDown = isDown;}
          else if (keyCode == 37) { leftDown = isDown;}
        }

        jQuery(document).keydown( function(evt){onKeyUpDown(evt,true);}).keyup( function(evt){onKeyUpDown(evt,false);});

        window.setInterval(
          function(){
            var upDownTxt = upDown?"up":"-"; ;
            var downDownTxt = downDown?"down":"-";
            var leftDownTxt = leftDown?"left":"-";
            var rightDownTxt = rightDown?"right":"-";
            jQuery("#out2").html(upDownTxt + "<br/>" + downDownTxt + "<br/>" + leftDownTxt + "<br/>" + rightDownTxt );
          },
          100);

      })();

    </script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/edavi3/edit

Comment: That is very good thanks, though I am still not understanding why one of the directions are not working while the others are.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I re-factored your code:

```
$(function() {
    var x = 150,
        y = 150,
        dx = 2,
        dy = 2,        
        canvas = $('#canvas'),
        ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d'),
        width = canvas.width(),
        height = canvas.height(),
        keys = {},
        intervalId = 0;

    function circle(x, y, r) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }

    $(document).keydown(function(e) { keys[e.which] = true; });
    $(document).keyup(function(e) { keys[e.which] = false; });

    intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        x = x - (keys['37'] ? dx : 0) + (keys['39'] ? dx : 0);
        y = y - (keys['38'] ? dy : 0) + (keys['40'] ? dy : 0);
        circle(x, y, 10);
    }, 20);
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/avSvu/4/