# Scroll div with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is similar to [SO: how to move a div with arrow keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950575/how-to-move-a-div-with-arrow-keys), so maybe a clear and informed 'no' suffices as an answer:

Can I make an overflowing div a "default scroll target" that reacts to arrow-up/down/page-down/space *the same way as an overflowing document* (i.e. scrolls down the content)? The page itself does not have a scrollbar (simple example below). In particular, can this be accomplished **without explicitly tracking key events** (neither directly nor hidded by a JS library)?

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="contentcontainer" style="height:200px;width:200px;overflow:scroll">
   <div id="innercontent" style="height:2000px;">foo</div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** Of course the above works after I click into the div. Basically, I want to avoid having to do that...

Comment: have you thought about simply [styling the scrollbars](http://websitetips.com/articles/css/scrollbars/) of the div and enforcing some sort of focus on it

Comment: yes but you still need to focus the div element. Why you dont just try, i went to a site and just clicked into the overflowing div, and used keys, no problem... but an "auto-focus" you will not be able to accomplish i think...7

Comment: I don't care about the styling. "Enforcing some sort of focus" may be what I am looking for... ;) How would that work?

Comment: I don't know how styling the scrollbars will help with this problem... (and you should not style the scrollbars, it is unsupported microsoft css extension)

Comment: Styled scrollbars are supported in WebKit too, and it's a useful feature. I don't see any reason not to style them.

Answer (score 13):

In order for an html element to be focusable, it must be reachable with the Tab key. This means you can call `.focus()` on a link or an input. Additionally, `body` elements are always focusable.

You need to make your div reachable with the Tab key. You can accomplish this by setting the `tabindex` property on it. If you do not actually want people to be able to tab into that div, you can set the tabindex to -1, which will prevent people from actually tabbing to it but will otherwise set the element up for tabbing and focus.

Source: http://help.dottoro.com/ljpkdpxb.php

Comment: After ensuring the div had a tabindex attribute, and then calling div.focus(), it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

Browsers usually have this behavior built-in,

In order to use arrow keys to scroll down your div, you must have an element within focused.

Lookup http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: Even after doing a `.focus()` on a form element within a div, Google Chrome does not recognize the div as the target of arrow key scroll keystrokes.