# Not able to use keyboard arrows to scroll my website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Small description of what I have done so far:--

I am making a website which have functionality of horizontal scroll with pagepiling when content on horizontal scroll ends. and after that a section with vertical scroll is present.

The Problem:--

The problem I am facing is that when website is visible to use, I am not able to use arrow keys to scroll until I click on any part of the website.when I click on any part of the website then only arrow keys works. This happens on both the section horizontal scroll section and vertical scroll section.

everything works perfectly when i click on any part of the window. before that arrow keys don't work.

Solution That I Need:--

What I want is when my site completely loads to use .then I can operate it using arrow keys of keyboards.

hope anyone can help me.

**Update**

pp-scrollable class is of Pagepiling.js which allow me to scroll the section with having more content.

pp-scrollable section losses its focus .. to use keyboard arrows to scroll first I click on any part of the pp-scrollable section then only I can use arrow keys to scroll

Comment: if your site does not have focus your keys will not work (maybe other window has the focus). Did you try to set focus in some control?

Comment: can u please tell me how to check that.

Comment: se vc usa jQuery, probably you have a ready function in your javascript. Just try to set the focus to some element, something like this: `$( document ).ready(function() {
    // other codes...
    $('#someId').focus();
});`

Comment: it didnt worked for me ...

Comment: You may need to set `tabindex`. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805550/scroll-div-with-arrow-keys

Answer (score 0):

Check what part of the site has focus when you load. If a text field has focus for example, you won't be able to scroll until you click somewhere else.

Comment: can u please tell me how to check that.