# (JQuery) Moving diagonally on key press

Tags: jquery

```
$("html").keydown(function(event){

        if(event.which == "37")
            $("#hero").animate({"left" : "-=30px"});

        if(event.which == "39")
            $("#hero").animate({"left" : "+=30px"});

        if(event.which == "38")
            $("#hero").animate({"top" : "-=30px"});

        if(event.which == "40")
            $("#hero").animate({"top" : "+=30px"});
});
```

How can I enable #hero to move diagonally?

Comment: be sure to use `keyup()` NOT `keydown()`. `keydown` acts weird in different browsers

Comment: keyup()???? But that's for when the key is released. #hero will only move when the key is released.

Comment: Check out [**my demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bDMnX/7/) presented in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950575/how-to-move-a-div-with-arrow-keys/4951670#4951670).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Check my updated [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gFcuU/103/)

Reference: [Can jQuery .keypress() detect more than one key at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954403/can-jquery-keypress-detect-more-than-one-key-at-the-same-time)

Also check out the comment from **Sime Vidas**.. Nice animation.. His post: [how to move a div with arrow keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950575/how-to-move-a-div-with-arrow-keys/4951670#4951670)

--- Old Post ---

Check my [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/gFcuU/99/) here..

The transition is not smooth and there are some issues.. I am trying to figure out why..

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to .animate() is a hash, so you can include more than one property. This would move #hero 30px up and 30px to the left:

```
$("#hero").animate({"left" : "-=30px", "top" : "-=30px"});
```

Comment: i think the OP is looking for a way to detect when two keys are pressed simultaneously

Comment: Exactly, I'm looking for a way to detect when 2 keys are pressed at the same time.