# How to move a div with arrow keys in percent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

I got this script from another question [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950575/how-to-move-a-div-with-arrow-keys) and it works perfectly. The script updates the element in px, and I specially like the way you can move the element diagonally by holding up+left arrow keys for instance.

My question now is: Is it possible to change the script so it sets and updates values of the element in percent instead?

The reason for this is that I'm developing a site with responsive design and I need the elements to stay (and move) on the page relative to the window size. I have tried to figure it out, but no success so far.

Here is the script:

HTML

```
<div id="pane">
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#pane {
    position:relative;
    width:300px; height:300px;
    border:2px solid red;
}

#box {
    position:absolute; top:140px; left:140px;
    width:20px; height:20px;          
    background-color:black;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var pane = $('#pane'),
    box = $('#box'),
    w = pane.width() - box.width(),
    d = {},
    x = 3;

function newv(v,a,b) {
    var n = parseInt(v, 10) - (d[a] ? x : 0) + (d[b] ? x : 0);
    return n < 0 ? 0 : n > w ? w : n;
}

$(window).keydown(function(e) { d[e.which] = true; });
$(window).keyup(function(e) { d[e.which] = false; });

setInterval(function() {
    box.css({
        left: function(i,v) { return newv(v, 37, 39); }, //Function should set values in %
        top: function(i,v) { return newv(v, 38, 40); }   //here for left and top
    });
}, 20);
```

COFFE SCRIPT

```
jQuery ->       
    pane = $('body')
    box = $('.myDiv')
    w = pane.width() - box.width()
    c = [37,38,39,40] # Set key values for arrow keys in an array
    d = []
    x = 4

    newv = (v,a,b) ->
        n = parseInt(v, 10) - (if d[a] then x else 0) + (if d[b] then x else 0)
        if n < 0 then 0 else if n > w then w else n

    $(window).keydown((e) ->
        d[e.which] = true
    )

    $(window).keyup((e) -> 
        d[e.which] = false
        if true not in d and e.which in c #Check that all arrow keys are released

        divID = $('.myDiv').attr('id')  # Grab values from the element
        top = $('.myDiv').css('top')
        left = $('.myDiv').css('left')

        setTimeout ->  #Set a timeout and then send element values with Ajax to database to preserve state of element for next time window is opened
            $.ajax(
                type: "PUT"
                url: "/url/to/update/database"
                data:
                    positiontop: top
                    positionleft: left
            )
            ,1000
         )

    setInterval ->
        box.css
            left: (i,v) ->
                newv(v, 37, 39)
            top: (i,v) -> 
                newv(v, 38, 40)
    ,40
```

Comment: You took this code somewhere and now you want us to change it for you. What have **you** done to solve **your** problem?

Comment: Well, I think I have figured out that the change to a percent value has to take place in the function newv(v,a,b). So I have tried to recalculate n with something like n/$(window).height()*100. Also tried do the same with the x in that function. Makes more sense to do the recalculation with the x values...

Comment: I have also translated this JavaScript to CoffeeScript and added some features. Is it a good practice here to post my changes maybe?

Comment: I added my Coffee Script if someone should have use for it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is what I ended up doing. It probably can use some tweaking to make the code more efficient, and I probably also will make the percent calculation values use one decimal to make the moving of the div more smoother.

I ran into one problem with Firefox and Opera: In the **setInterval-function** the **v** value is returned in pixels. So I added the **v = box[0].style.left** and **v = box[0].style.top** to get the value returned as percent in all browsers.

Since the browser window isn't always a square, I also added another function to calculate the width and height separately.

JavaScript

```
var pane = $(window),
    box = $('#box'),
    w = (pane.width() - box.width())/pane.width()*100,
    h = (pane.height() - box.height())/pane.height()*100,
    d = {},
    x = 1;

//Caclulate height movement and window height bounds in %
function newvHeight(v,a,b) {
    v = box[0].style.top  //Grab :top value of the #box div as % in all browsers
    var n = parseInt(v, 10) - (d[a] ? x : 0) + (d[b] ? x : 0);
    return (n < 0 ? 0 : n > h ? h : n) + '%';
}

//Calculate width movement and window width bounds in %
function newvWidth(v,a,b) {
    v = box[0].style.left   //Grab :left value of the #box div as % in all browsers
    var n = parseInt(v, 10) - (d[a] ? x : 0) + (d[b] ? x : 0);
    return (n < 0 ? 0 : n > w ? w : n) + '%';
}

$(window).keydown(function(e) { d[e.which] = true; });
$(window).keyup(function(e) { d[e.which] = false; });

setInterval(function() {
    box.css({
        left: function(i,v) { return newvWidth(v, 37, 39); },   //Function should set values in %
        top: function(i,v) { return newvHeight(v, 38, 40); }    //here for left and top
    });
}, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track according to your comment. You have to figure out what his code is doing. He is using [ternary operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788917/javascript-ternary-operator) which you may not be familiar with. I will use his return variable line to help explain it.

```
return n < 0 ? 0 : n > w ? w : n;
```

This says, return n if it is less than zero or greater than the box width. Otherwise leave it alone because we are at a boundary. In your case you would want it to return `n > 0 or < 100`. Then you just need to change it to return in terms of % instead of px. You do that by appending '%'.

http://jsfiddle.net/bDMnX/332/

```
w = 100; //pane.width() - box.width(),

function newv(v,a,b) {
    var n = parseInt(v, 10) - (d[a] ? x : 0) + (d[b] ? x : 0);
    //console.log((n < 0 ? 0 : n > w ? w : n) + '%');   
    return (n < 0 ? 0 : n > w ? w : n) + '%';
}
```

I will leave getting the bounding and incrementing up to you.

Comment: Ahhh....thank you. No I was not familiar with ternary operators, I will read up the subject.