# Moving a box in JavaScript again -- the program seems to be detecting two key presses even though I'm only pressing one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build on the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950575/how-to-move-a-div-with-arrow-keys) by adding "gravity" such that the box always moves down unless a key is pressed.

I've been fiddling for a couple of hours now and I can't figure it out. In the previous code he send two variables to the calculateNewValue function, for top and left of the css position.

I thought I would simply be able to break these two tests for true/false key presses out into four, and then add a +1 for when the up arrow is false, hence the box will always fall down unless you tell it not to.

It almost works, but the box moves down and to the right, instead of just down. And gravity doesn't work like that.

This must have something to do with top and left being used to move the box in two directions. But if the event handler is storing the keycode for only one key, wouldn't all the other tests return false? How can I get it to not move right?

```
$(function(){

var pane = $('#pane'),
    box = $('#box'),
    maxValue = pane.width() - box.width(),
    keysPressed = {},
    distancePerIteration = 3;

function calculateNewValue(oldValue) {
    var newValue = parseInt(oldValue, 10)
                   - (keysPressed[37] ? distancePerIteration : 0)
                   - (keysPressed[38] ? distancePerIteration : 0)
                   + (keysPressed[39] ? distancePerIteration : 0)
                   + (keysPressed[40] ? distancePerIteration : 1)
    return newValue < 0 ? 0 : newValue > maxValue ? maxValue : newValue;
}

$(window).keydown(function(event) { keysPressed[event.which] = true; });
$(window).keyup(function(event) { keysPressed[event.which] = false; });

setInterval(function() {
    box.css({
        left: function(index ,oldValue) {
            return calculateNewValue(oldValue);
        },
        top: function(index, oldValue) {
            return calculateNewValue(oldValue);
        }   
    });
}, 20);

});
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling one of the key presses (keydown/keyup) to see if only the other is activated?

Comment: `function calculateNewValue(){...}` looks wrong. How can it address x and y separately when it returns one value? Why does `keysPressed[40]` not follow the same pattern as the other three keys?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you only use keyup() function. Then the keypress will only fire one event. Only in special cases it is necessary to use keydown().

Answer (score 0):

Your code is flawed. Every 20 milliseconds you modify the the left/top of the box by the same amount every time.

The way you have set up the code, the left and top values always increase by the same amount every time the CSS is updated - so the box will always move either upleft or downright depending on if you press left/up keys.

If you're just trying to move the box up and down then you probably want to change the code not to modify the left attribute - and then change the calculateNewValue to not use the ascii for left/right arrows.

Comment: Aha! I see the mistake, the code is tagging the key press to both the top and the left elements. Thanks, back to the drawing board!