# Tron game keyevent issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a 'Tron-game like' little game, heres the code, i already made: http://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Y/KQW5w/2/
code snippet:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {
            // leftArrowPressed
            palette.leftArrowPressed();
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
            //  topArrowPressed
            palette.topArrowPressed();
        } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            // rightArrowPressed
            palette.rightArrowPressed();
        } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            // bottomArrowPressed
            palette.bottomArrowPressed();
        }

        return false;
    });

Palette.prototype.leftArrowPressed = function () {
    this.X = this.X - this.game.speed;
    this.context.lineTo(this.X, this.Y);
    this.context.stroke();
}
```

The problem is, when i press one of the arrow keys and draw a line, then press a different arrow key, there is a little break on the drawing, so the line-drawing is not continuous :/
Any advice?

Comment: Have a `setTimeout` that loops every X ms. Have a keyhandler that stores which keys are being pressed. In the timer callback act accordingly.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4951670/425275 (try the demo)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any break in the demo you provided.

Anyway, the first time you push an arrow, no line is drawn.

I updated your code, by setting the `palette.context.beginPath()` instruction before `palette.context.moveTo()`, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HighKickX/KQW5w/3/) for the result.

```
palette.context.beginPath();
palette.context.moveTo(palette.X, palette.Y);
```