# Keyboard Arrow Key Controls in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
 function control()
            {
                var ship = document.getElementById("ship");
                document.onkeydown = function(e) { 
                    switch (e.keyCode) { 
                        case 38: 
                            ship.style.top += "5%"; 
                            break;
                        case 40: 
                            ship.style.top -= "5%"; 
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    } 
                }
            }
setInterval(control,1000);
```

This code is not working.

The object I'm trying to move is not moving when I'm pressing the Up & Down Arrow Key.

Comment: Your code detects the keys pressed! Look the problem is here ship.style.top += "5%";.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to move a div with arrow keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950575/how-to-move-a-div-with-arrow-keys)

Comment: No need to use setInterval(control,1000);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like that:

```
const ship = document.getElementById("ship");
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    let winHeigth = window.innerHeight;
    let top = ship.style.top;
    switch (e.code) {
        case "ArrowUp":
            ship.style.top = (Number(top.substring(0, top.length - 2)) - (winHeigth / 20)) + "px";
            break;
        case "ArrowDown":
            ship.style.top = (Number(top.substring(0, top.length - 2)) + (winHeigth / 20)) + "px";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

The position attribute of the "ship" must be like "relative".
By the way, e.keyCode is deprecated, you can use e.code instead ^^

Comment: Will it work with % ? As I want my page to work with the similar dimensions on a mobile device too.

Comment: Yes, you can also do this: ship.style.top = (Number(top.substring(0, top.length - 1)) - 5) + "%";

Comment: Well this code is generating an Error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at HTMLDocument.document.onkeydown (game.html:167)

Comment: Error In this line 
`let top = ship.style.top;`

Comment: Did you defined ship ?

Comment: Yes I've done it in My previous function in which the ship is constantly moving
`var ship = document.getElementById("ship");   
                var pos = 0;
                var id = setInterval(frame, 0.5);
                function frame() {
                    pos+=0.1;
                    ship.style.left = pos + "%";
                    if (pos > 85)
                    {
                        pos = 0;
                    }
                }
`

Comment: So, I've remove your first line of the code. My old function is still working fine but key pressing generates an error to the function (e).

Comment: Yes, if you removed the ship definition, it's normal that it doesn't work as well ...
Maybe you have a scope misunderstanding

Comment: After removing your line , it is not generating error but ignoring the function.

Comment: Here is the script.
[link](https://www.writeurl.com/text/clydp04b7oenagsskczf/fedpx9cq3wu31wpnrwoz/vidoxwtw5h8arwitjh50)

Comment: Your code works, the only "issue" is that we can only move the ship one step upper and one step lower...  EDIT: replace the "%" by "px" and this issue disappears

Comment: Yes !! Finally !

Answer (score 1):

You can't do

```
ship.style.top += "5%";
```

because ship.style.top value is not a number but a string. the += opérator is concatening strings here.