# Why is my div element not moving based on my movement functions?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to move my div element by having the body sense what key button I pressed, finding the right key symbol w, a, x, d, and then subtracting or adding from the css attributes of the html elements.

However it does not work and whenever I console log the elements or its attributes, nothing appears. The mover will not move.

```js
var mover; 


function moveDivBlock(e){
    if ((e.keyCode == 69) ||(e.keyCode == 68)||(e.keyCode == 67)){//go right
        moveBlock(mover,10,0);}
    if ((e.keyCode == 81) ||(e.keyCode == 65)||(e.keyCode == 90)){//go left
        moveBlock(mover,-10,0);}
    if ((e.keyCode == 81) ||(e.keyCode == 87)||(e.keyCode == 69)){//go up
        moveBlock(mover,0,10);}
    if ((e.keyCode == 90) ||(e.keyCode == 88)||(e.keyCode == 67)){//go down
        moveBlock(mover,0,-10);}
}

function handleKeyDown(e) {
    moveDivBlock(e);
}


function moveBlock(elem, rightShift, upShift){
    var curLeft = parseInt(elem.style.left); 
    var curTop = parseInt(elem.style.top); 
    elem.style.left = (curLeft + rightShift) + "px"; 
    elem.style.top = (curTop - upShift) + "px"; 
}


window.onload=function(){
    mover=document.getElementById("mover");
}
```

```css
    #mover{
        position:absolute;
        top:290px;
        left:130px;
    
        background-color:green;
        width:50px; 
        height:50px; 
        border:2px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<body onkeydown="handleKeyDown(event);">
        <div id="mover"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you check, if `mover` is defined, when you call the `moveBlock` function? Also why do you subtract `upShift`, when you add `rightShift`?

Comment: Because `elem.style` is not defined in `moveBlock` function, and the math gives `NaN`. You've to set the inline styles for the position in order to able to read the styles.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4951670/7750416

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this was not working, `elem.style.top` returns inline style only, not style from css file. To get style from css file you need to use `getComputedStyle(elem)`. Please try this

```
function moveBlock(elem, rightShift, upShift){
    var curLeft = parseInt(getComputedStyle(elem).left); 
    var curTop = parseInt(getComputedStyle(elem).top); 
    elem.style.left = (curLeft + rightShift) + "px"; 
    elem.style.top = (curTop - upShift) + "px"; 
}
```

Comment: @jabaa yours is also working man, you are in too much hurry it looks

Comment: I tested both the jsfiddles, and I can confirm that it also works for me.